# Strict Transport Security header for SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS 14)

Tags: ssrs-2012, hsts

How to enable `Strict Transport Security` header for `SQL Server Reporting Services(SSRS 14)`.There is a custom code in `ASP` for logging in. Tried to add headers in web config of Report manager and Server dut it doesn't not work.

Tried to do it in the `ASpx.cs` pages as well. Any solution or approach would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and it appears the ability to add this header (or any custom header) was added to SSRS 2019. Reference [article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/server-properties-advanced-page-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15).